# Why is my first roll out of my program not random?

Tags: c++, random, dice

This program is a game of craps. The program runs perfectly fine, with the exception that every time the program starts up, it gives me the same random number, but if you keep on playing the game and start a new game without exiting the console, the first roll number is apparently random, seeing as how I can't predict what it will be after the `again()` function, but when the code first starts up, the first roll is always ten. I have been trying to figure out the problem on my own and I can't seem to find anyone with a craps game coded how I did it, but maybe someone can help me out here.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

//main prototype
int main();

//score system
int wins = 0;
int loses = 0;

int again(){
    int answer;
    cout << "\nWould you like to play another round? (1=y,2=n)\n" << endl;
    cin >> answer;
    cout << endl;
    cout << endl;

    if(answer==1){
        main();
    }else if(answer==2){
        cout << "thanks for playing homie" << endl;
        return 0;
    }else{
        cout << "I'm sorry what?" << endl;
        again();
    }

}//end of again

class DiceClass{
public:
    DiceClass(){
        srand(time(0));
    }

    int firstdiceroll = 2+rand()%11;

    void PhaseOne(){
        cout << "Lets play some craps. \n" << endl;
        system("pause");
        cout << endl;

        cout << "You rolled " << firstdiceroll << "." << endl;

        if(firstdiceroll==7 || firstdiceroll==11){
            cout << "You win!!" << endl;
            wins++;
            cout << "Currents wins: " << wins << "\nCurrent loses: " << loses << endl;
            again();
        }
        else if(firstdiceroll==2 || firstdiceroll==3 || firstdiceroll==12){
            cout << "You lose!" << endl;
            loses++;
            cout << "Currents wins: " << wins << "\nCurrent loses: " << loses << endl;
            again();
        }
        else{
            cout << "Rolling again!\n" << endl;
            system("pause");
            cout << endl;
            PhaseTwo();
        }
    } //ends PhaseOne

    void PhaseTwo(){
        int seconddiceroll = 2+rand()%11;
        cout << "You rolled " << seconddiceroll << endl;
        if(firstdiceroll==seconddiceroll){
            cout << "You win!!" << endl;
            wins++;
            cout << "Currents wins: " << wins << "\nCurrent loses: " << loses << endl;
            again();
        }
        else if(seconddiceroll==7){
            cout << "You lose!" << endl;
            loses++;
            cout << "Currents wins: " << wins << "\nCurrent loses: " << loses << endl;
            again();
        }
        else{
            cout << "Rolling again." << endl;
            system("pause");
            cout << endl;
            PhaseTwo();
        }
    } //ends PhaseTwo
}; //ends DiceClass

int main()
{
    DiceClass DObject1;
    DObject1.PhaseOne();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Off topic: Calling `main` from anywhere within a C++ program  is a bad, bad, bad idea. Sayeth **basic.start.main**: "The function main shall not be used within a program." What will happen if you do it doesn't appear to be defined.

Answer (score 3):

```
class DiceClass{
public:
   DiceClass(){
      srand(time(0));
   }

   int firstdiceroll = 2+rand()%11;

   // etc.
};
```

The member variables of the class are initialized *before* entering the body of the constructor. So the `firstdiceroll` is set just before changing the random number sequence.

Comment: That definitely makes sense to me, but when I tried initializing inside of the constructor (i tried that first, to permanently set firstdiceroll until the program looped and changed it) nothing seems to recognize firstdiceroll. but also, why is it apparently random when it loops around again? maybe a better question is how do i seed the random number generator AND initialize the first dice roll

Comment: @lilbigwill99: Move the initialisation of `firstdiceroll` to the proper place.

Comment: @lilbigwill99 Leave the declaration `int firstdiceroll;` where it is, but move its initialization `firstdiceroll = 2+rand()%11;` into the constructor.

Comment: @pjs thank you my friend it works fine! in the quickest way possible,is it possible you can explain why your way works instead of mine?

Comment: @lilbigwill99 It's exactly what Bo says above - "member variables of the class are initialized before entering the body of the constructor."  When you write `int firstdiceroll = 2+rand()%11;` it's using `rand()` *before* the constructor has been invoked, so that first assignment is using the default (constant) seed value.  By separating the assignment out into the constructor, `rand()` gets seeded *before* the first assignment.

Comment: @pjs thanks homie i really appreciate it, i have tried my best to stay off forums and try and figure it out myself and most cases it works but i could not figure this one out lmao. thank you